# raspberry pi unable to stream video to vlc

Tags: gstreamer, raspberry-pi, vlc

I am trying to stream a video from my raspberry pi to vlc player using hardware h264 encoding. Following is my pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///root/sintel_trailer-480p.webm !   omxh264enc ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=134.202.84.72 port=1234
```

The vlc player is buffering the video but unable to play and it continously displays the following message

```
packetizer_h264 warning: waiting for SPS/PPS
```

please help

Comment: Hi user1669463,

I suspect you're trying to send a lot of information over the network and it's having a hard time processing everything. Have you tried adding a queue to your pipeline?

eg:

    gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///root/sintel_trailer-480p.webm !  queue name=qstream ! omxh264enc ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=134.202.84.72 port=1234

Comment: Thanks @MalcolmJones i tried it but still no luck. If i use some other video encoding schemes it works e.g if i use theoraenc     gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///root/sintel_trailer-480p.webm ! theoraenc  !  oggmux ! tcpserversink host=134.202.84.72  it works fine but i need to use hardware H264 encoder of raspberry-pi for my application

Comment: @MalcolmJones if i  a make a file of the video using the following pipeline   gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! videoparse  width=320 height=240   ! omxh264enc  ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=xyz.flv  and then copy the to my pc through usb vlc player plays it comfortably

Answer (score 2):

I think you have answered your own question.

The difference in your pipelines is that in the one that works, you insert SPS/PPS every second (config-interval=1).

So try this:

```
uri="file:///root/sintel_trailer-480p.webm"

gst-launch-1.0 \
    uridecodebin uri="$uri" \
    ! omxh264enc ! h264parse config-interval=1 \
    ! mpegtsmux \
    ! tcpserversink host=134.202.84.72 port=1234
```

Comment: i have also tried forgot to mention it before but still same response from vlc

Comment: When I piped the raspivid it removed the d the problem with the SPS/PPS and the frame size gets set in VLC with driectx but the video is black. I tried the webm file that still complains with missing SPS/PPS using the config-interval=1